# Writing into many to many join tables using ids only

Tags: java, jpa

In a `@ManyToOne` relation it's possible to handle the writes of the relation by setting the id of the related table:

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "bar_id")
    private Long barId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Bar bar;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Bar{
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar")
    private List<Foo> foos;
    // ...
}
```

In many situations(ex: when constructing an instance of `Bar` is difficult) this is a better way of persisting a `Foo` related to a `Bar` rather than setting `foo.bar` to an empty instance and setting the `id` of that instance. How can you achieve something similar in a `@ManyToMany` relation?

Comment: Both using the above approach and 'setting `foo.bar` to an empty instance and setting the `id` of that instance' seem terrible ideas to me. If you want to establish an association to an entity, without fetching that entity, use `EntityManager.getReference(entityClass, id)`

Comment: @crizzis the proposed approach should be used when you want to persist a new instance of `Foo` with the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the `@ManyToOne` example you can only persist relations by setting the `barIds` field and `bars` field is readonly:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "foo_bars", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foos_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Column(name = "bars_id")
    private Set<Long> barIds;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<Bar> bars;
    // ...
}
```